# Attempt to apply non- function, randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a data set(train2) with 79 variables(numeric and text combined) and the SalePrice as the last column. I am trying to create a randomForest model, this is what I get as an error:

```
Forest <- randomForest(SalePrice~., data = train2, na.action = TRUE)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = SalePrice ~ ., data = train2, na.action = TRUE) : 
attempt to apply non-function
```

Do you have any idea how I can solve this error?

Comment: I believe `na.action` expects a function not a boolean. So it should be one of `na.omit`, `na.exclude`, etc. I think.

Answer (score 1):

@joran is correct. I also want to steer you in the direction of exploring these two:

***ntree*** Number of trees to grow. This should not be set to too small a number, to ensure
that every input row gets predicted at least a few times.

***mtry*** Number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split. Note that
the default values are different for classification (sqrt(p) where p is number of
variables in x) and regression (p/3)